# jQuery Resize Div Responsive

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I am trying to make a script that will complete an equal height function above a certain resolution.

Once below that resolution I would like the script to turn off as the equal height columns go away on the mobile version of the site.

I would like this to execute on resize as well. Here is my code so far. This doesn't work at all.

The stretch function does and has been tested outside of the check Width function.

Here is my Code :

**Original Stretch Function**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $stretch = $(".eq");
    $stretch.animate({ height: $stretch.parent().height() }, 300 );
});
```

**Resize Function That Does Not Work**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);
    var $stretch = $("#narrow")
    var $stretch2 = $(".eq")

    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize > 440) {
            //if the window is greater than 440px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
            $stretch.animate({ height: $stretch.parent().height() }, 800 );
            $stretch.animate({ height: $stretch2.parent().height() }, 300 );                
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sulthan why are you editing this? 'Optimalisation' isn't even a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the jquery part

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // do your stuff here

    checkWidth();
});
```

If you use media queries with combination of the js, keep in mind that the media query width and the `$(window).width()` are different due to scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm sad stack overflow didn't inform me of these answers sooner. I actually figured this out and have way less mark up then above.

Comment: @RossEdman, please post your edits below your question for future users. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend to use CSS instead of jQuery for such a thing. Responsive UI can be handled by media query like these:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    body{ width:1000px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    body{ width:440px; }
}
```

There is lot of great tools to simplify you this, one of the most popular is [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).

Comment: For IE8 you need to get the media query js

Comment: I completely agree with your answer. However, not what I was looking for. Thanks so much though. I needed this for a very specific function which was a column height script for desktop only that I wanted to turn off below a certain screen resolution.